# How do I change the headers that PHP sends when using file_get_contents on an external URL?

Tags: php, header, file-get-contents

I need to change the headers that PHP sends when it requests a file using file_get_contents(). Is that possible or would I have to use CURL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in conjunction with [stream_context_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)

Exemple :

```
<?php
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
));
$out = file_get_contents($filename, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CURL. It's also more reliable. See curl_setopt and CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.